# azure activity log, how to find releases

Tags: azure, azure-devops, logging

My security department has asked to ingest logs from Azure with the goal being to identity releases. The security team wants to be able to say:

> Hey, there was a release on mm/dd/yyyy at noon (because we see it in the Azure logs), show me the
>   corresponding internal approval for that?

I've been looking around in the [Azure Activity Log](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog/), but I can't seem to find anything related to releases, overwrites, or anything else that's clearly new-code being dropped onto a PaaS instance.

Like I'm pretty sure there was a release (devops build/release, pushed the code to a Paas) during this timeframe but I'm not seeing it.

[image]

Is there a way to do this? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Edit: my little highlight there on the "Write Event" isn't related, just something that happened to a database at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Logs can only able to show the resource level logs like creating a resources,deleting a resources modify the SKU of the resources etc,

Assuming from your question you are saying web app deployment from azure devops,which is more like a deployment of code to an existing webapp which will not be covered by activity logs. You need to go to that azure app service then you can that deployment details in `Deployment Center`

[image]